# React Native Expo Location Permission throwing Location Provider warning

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, location, expo

I'm trying to create a react native app using expo.
My app needs user permission to get the current location.
I have a functional component that has `useEffect()` hook to get permission asynchronously.
Code below.

```
const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            let permissionStatus = null;
            if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                let {status} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
                permissionStatus = status;
            } else {
                let {status} = await ExpoLocation.requestPermissionsAsync();
                permissionStatus = status;
            }
            if (permissionStatus !== 'granted') {
                return;
            }
            let location = await ExpoLocation.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
            setLocation(location);
            console.log(location);
        })();
    }, []);
```

It sometimes works without any flaws but some other times throws this warning:
**Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Location provider is unavailable. Make sure that location services are enabled.**
The app shows the permission request dialog and after agreeing it turns on the location services in the phone but still throws this warning/error.
After a thorough research on this website and some other I have added `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` to my `app.json.android.permissions` config and experimented with some other values, but at the end I still faced this problem often.
It is worth to mention, with all the permutations of the configs the code works perfectly and sometimes throws this error/warning for the same config.
I'm using **Expo SDK 40** and `expo-location` package version is **~10.0.0** and testing on **Android 10** phone using **Expo Go** client app.
I would appreciate any insights or advices on how to solve this problem.
Feel free to ask for any clarifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue feels similar to one I researched within the past year. In my code, I ended up adding enableHighAccuracy too which I think helped. But the fact that it's an Unhandled Promise Rejection suggests that you should add a try/catch at least to gracefully handle if it breaks for any reason.

```
gpsLocationFromDevice = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({ enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

Comment: This is an old post of mine that someone may stumble on looking for location provider info. I noticed that forum threads are waking up recently because of systemic issues with location getLocation method not reliably reporting anymore through no fault of the coders (hit me too). Simplest workaround was to ask getLocation in a loop until the location is found. Will try to find that link and add here for posterity but in case I don't remember to put it here, I just wanted to encourage others who land here to seek out that specific bug if they're suddenly seeing unstable getLocation asyc calls.